# After GzipCompression JSON data from client for Post request Using HttpClientBuilder getting blank params at Server

Tags: java, json, http, post

I have used HttpClientBuilder 4.3.3.jar

I need to send compressed json params in Post request to server, but on server I m getting request parameters blank

```
CloseableHttpClient client = 

HttpClientBuilder.create().useSystemProperties().build();

HttpClientContext context = setClientCredentials(client, username, password, uri);

HttpPost post_method= new HttpPost( uri);

HttpEntity entity = EntityBuilder.create().setText(params).setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON).gzipCompress().build();

post_method.setEntity(entity);  

client.execute(post_method)
```

Comment: JSON parameters in the POST body will not come through as request parameters. You'll need to parse the body as JSON

Comment: When I m sending JSON params without compression then the parameters are in request parameters

HttpEntity entity = EntityBuilder.create().setText(params).setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();

{"data"=>{"attributes"=>{"clientAppId"=>"niru_bpm_test", "name"=>"BPM_test_new_1"}, "type"=>"applications"}

Comment: I just checked even request body is blank